# maven compile C# source code into exe using mvn-compiler plugin

Tags: java, c#, maven

At the moment I'm using a pom like this to generate a DLL it works,but I can't figure out how to generate an .exe file in the same way .
Thanks you all for suggestions .

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<compilerId>csharp</compilerId>
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe</executable>
<outputFileName>myDll</outputFileName>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
<artifactId>plexus-compiler-csharp</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: using mvn -X clean package I've noticed that the command executed is :
/debug+
/out:C:\Users\test1\Desktop\prova1\target\classes\myDll.dll
/target:library
C:\Users\test1\Desktop\prova1\src\main\java\dev\Myclass.cs
How can I specify a simple /out:myEXE ../Myclass.cs ?
I'm not able to find info how to use this plugin .